# Fetch API data and render as div cards

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a project that I am trying to render fetched API data into div cards for a real estate website. This is what I have tried so far:

```
fetch("URL, {
   "method": "GET",
   "headers": {
       "//Access Key Here",
       "//Host Info Here"
   }
})
.then(response => response.json ())
.then(properties => displayProperties(properties.results));
displayProperties = properties => {
 const propertiesDiv = document.querySelector(`#propertyContainer`);
    properties.forEach(property => {

      const propertyElement = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.textContent = property.formattedAddress;

        const p = document.createElement('p');
           p.innerText = `Number Bathrooms: ${property.bathrooms}`;
           p.innerText = `Number Bedrooms: ${property.bedrooms}`;
           p.innerText = `Number Bedrooms: ${property.bedrooms}`;
           p.innerText = `Property Type: ${property.propertyType}`;
           p.innerText = `Price: ${property.price}`;

           propertiesDiv.append(propertyElement);
           propertiesDiv.append(p);
     });
}
```

Project requires that I not use jQuery (ugh) and with this code I am getting:

> "Cannot read property forEach of undefined."

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like `properties` may not have a `result`; basically it's complaining about `properties.result` being `undefined`. Take a look at the response that comes back from the server.

Comment: This is probably due to referencing to a non array properties. Would be great if you could ```console.log``` ```properties``` & ```properties.results```.

Comment: ok so I tested my code again but instead of declaring "properties" I replaced with "json" seems the code does not like my displayProperties function. Does anyone know how many ".then" statements I can use in a given project? Reason asking is I could console log "json, results ...etc." in a bunch of then statements.

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot read property forEach of undefined."

The above in JavaScript means that, in `properties.forEach(`, `properties` has an `undefined` value.

On Reverse reading your code,
The following is mostly probable,

- If `properties` is `undefined`,
- The parameter passed to the function `displayProperties()` is `undefined`
- Therefore, `properties.result` is `undefined`

Based on the above observation,
I think you should `console.log(properties)` and check whether the result of `fetch()` actually has the key `properties.result`. I feel troubleshooting the API i.e., the `URL` you use in `fetch()` will help

You can use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) for troubleshooting your API or also use Chrome DevTools (Fn + F12) in Chrome or Firefox based browsers.